# How to have a variable save from previous queries? (Prometheus/Grafana)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I currently have a custom variable that saves the names of the branches I am testing, for example a and b. However, in the future I will have branches with different names and instead of manually putting in the names I would like to autofill it with a query. I used query_result(test) and regex to isolate the name I want, however this leads to only the most recent name tested being a variable and gets rid of the previous query results. Is there a way to query previous results as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `label_values` to get a list of label values. See: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable